# Recognizing when my machine has the IP of someone else

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip, linux-networking

From times to times my computer is very slow in accessing internet or going to the network. Few colleagues of mine suggested that my machine might have the same IP of another one and this would cause a clash in the network.

My questions are

1. How to find out whether this is true
2. Is there any command I can call to see who is the other guy having my IP

I have a Linux machine but few PCs use also Windows.

Comment: the best way is your machine should get ip address from dhcp server if you have dhcp server in your network . If you want to assign static ip then before assigning it to your machine make sure you consult it with your network admin.

Comment: In this case you should contact the system/network administrator and have them sort out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`arping` can help you in disvovering IP clashes. Just send an arping to the IP:

```
# arping 172.16.10.1
ARPING 172.16.10.1 from 172.16.10.204 eth0
Unicast reply from 172.16.10.1 [00:10:DB:FC:11:00]  0.982ms
Unicast reply from 172.16.10.1 [00:10:DB:FC:11:00]  0.966ms
Unicast reply from 172.16.10.1 [00:10:DB:FC:11:00]  0.975ms
Unicast reply from 172.16.10.1 [00:10:DB:FC:11:00]  22.517ms
^CSent 4 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s)
```

If you get replies from more than one MAC, more than one machine is using the IP. You can identify the machines via their MAC addresses.